# App Deployment: WSGI Server to go inside the Virtual ENV or installed globally?

Tags: python, webserver, virtualenv, wsgi, production-environment

The following question is aimed for two use cases.

- **Use case 1:** Deploying **a single** WSGI app on a single server.
- **Use case 2:** Deploying **one or more** WSGI apps on the same server.

**My question:**

- Should the WSGI server be installed inside the same virtualenv along the Python WSGI application itself? or;
- Should I have the WSGI server installed globally?

I am wondering about WSGI applications (based on frameworks) such as **Flask, CherryPy, Pyramid etc.**
And WSGI servers such as **Gunicorn, Waitress etc.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just go for virtualenv -- different apps with different libs can coexist peacefully; and if it's a single app only, it's still no harder to set up, but leaves you flexibility for the future.

Same applies to native WSGI servers, just install them into virtualenv, it won't hurt the performance.

What WILL hurt it is Python's multithreading because of [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), so stay away from native threaded servers like Waitress. Use multiprocess servers (or asynchronous, where it makes sense), which, I believe, Gunicorn is. Consider using [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/) -- it is very powerful, although not native.

Flask, etc are not applications, they are frameworks that let you develop your applications easier by relieving you from a burden of processing basic things like parsing paths, sending appropriate headers, etc. You just need to choose the one that suits your needs better.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I know that flask et al. are not applications. I was referring to applications based on them (the frameworks). Can you please elaborate on why to install web servers, if possible, inside venv whereas the ones that (such as uwsgi) which can't go inside the venv stay outside and as a setup it is ok?

Comment: @Phil: Say, you want to test a new version of a server but don't want all the apps affected like they would be with a global install --  basically same logic as with libs. And btw, uWSGI can be installed into virtualenv.

Comment: The comment about the impact of the GIL on multithreading WSGI servers doesn't really tell the whole picture. Most Python web applications are I/O bound and not CPU bound and so multithreading is quite okay. Multithreading is actually very much preferred if possible because as soon as you go multiprocess you require a lot more memory, which if you are using a PaaS means you are wasting more of your money paying the hosting service for extra memory or instances you do not need. Judicious use of multithreading means you can make more effective use of limited resources and save money.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, would you care to (please, I'd appreciate it) give a full answer on your thoughts about the main question? Thank you!

Comment: What is there to say. Having a virtualenv fallback to using modules in the site-packages directory of the Python installation it was based on is generally regarded as bad practice these days. This is why --no-site-packages is now the default for virtualenv. If relying on the default options for virtualenv, you therefore don't generally have a choice but to install the WSGI server into the Python virtual envrionment as it will not be found otherwise.

Comment: Even for IO-bound apps it's not that easy to tell if GIL will be a bottleneck (see http://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf). Also, if your app is really so highly IO-bound that you don't care about GIL, you should make it async.

Comment: Just came across the Python 3 GIL research by the same person: http://www.dabeaz.com/python/NewGIL.pdf. With the new GIL, any CPU-bound thread can block an IO-bound thread for up to 5 ms.