# cherrypy.HTTPRedirect redirects to IP instead of hostname using abs path

Tags: python-2.7, nginx, cherrypy

I'm running CherryPy behind nginx and need to handle redirects.  On my dev machine running on 127.0.0.1:8080, this redirects correctly to 127.0.0.1:8080/login.

However when running via nginx on cherrypy.mydomain.com (port 80), the redirects are still going to 127.0.0.1:8080/login rather than cherrypy.mydomain.com/login. 127.0.0.1:8080 is the correct local address for the application, however the application server in nginx is set to listen on port 80 and pipe requests to the local cherrypy server on 127.0.0.1:8080, but shouldn't directly expose this.

The relevant lines in my app are:

auth failure:

```
raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("/login")
```

and in my controller:

```
cherrypy.config.update({
    'tools.encode.on': True, 'tools.encode.encoding': 'utf-8',
    'tools.decode.on': True,
    'tools.trailing_slash.on': True,
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
})
```

I was wondering if there was an additional cherrypy config item for the server/host name in addition to the socket host, but I'm struggling to find it in the Docs.

Essentially, all I need is for cherrypy to redirect to the cherrypy.mydomain.com hostname rather than the internal IP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [tools.proxy](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.lib.html#cherrypy.lib.cptools.proxy) config setting:

```
'tools.proxy.on': True,
```

Additionally you may need

```
'tools.proxy.local': 'X-Forwarded-Host',
```

Set to appropriate header. When using **NGINX**, the header would be

```
'tools.proxy.local': 'Host',
```

In case of **Lighttpd** this header will be appropriate:

```python
'tools.proxy.local': 'X-Host'
```

Comment: I got this working using  your `'tools.proxy.on': True,` combined with `'tools.proxy.base': 'cherrypy.mydomain.com',`. tools.proxy.local didn't seem to do it (whether it by my error or a red herring, I'm not sure! Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: In fact, your solution works in its entirety.  The problem was that the header was incorrect (as you mentioned).  I mistakenly referred to the Apache docs (force of habit).  The nginx header is "Host".  I've updated your answer to reflect the nginx specific header. Thanks :)

Comment: I got an email notification about a comment, but I can't see it here now. Don't know if it was deleted?  Anyway, my question: Why would you use uWSGI rather than CherryPy's inbuilt WSGI compliant server?

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was a wrong place to mention uWSGI. But since you bring it up, see what I think about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286391/app-deployment-wsgi-server-to-go-inside-the-virtual-env-or-installed-globally/20289680#20289680

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add a comment to the https://stackoverflow.com/a/20730038/1115187 , but I know, that **Lighttpd** sends `X-Host` header, so for Lighttpd proxy use:

```python
'tools.proxy.local': 'X-Host'
```

Comment: How to get +2 rep: make a suggested edit on a post. Then you could comment properly.

Comment: Tada. You can delete this now.

Comment: @Mogsdad, strange stuff. I want to be the last editor;)

Comment: When reviewing pending edits, one has the choice to approve (which needs more people to do the same), reject (same), or approve + improve (one step). Your edit was good, but missed a couple of things that could further improve the question, so I added those. In the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20730038/revisions), it shows that you edited a revision, and then I did. If you can find more to suggest, go ahead... I'll leave it for the general review queue!