# CherryPy Finding the Domain that referred to the IP

Tags: python, url, webserver, cherrypy

I've implemented a web server in CherryPy that will be linked to via a number of different url sub domains , e.g. monkey.example.com cat.example.com

I need to know from which URL the web request has come from in order to processes their request in a slightly different way, whilst still using the main server program.

Is there a way to do this without running separate server instances for each sub domain? If so, how?

Comment: What do you use to make CherryPy receive requests from multiple domains? Whatever it is, a reverse proxy or CherryPy's virtual host dispatcher, update your question with appropriate config as it determines the answer.

Comment: See [my tools.proxy answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20730038/1914052). Basically it's `Host` or `X-Forwarded-Host` header.