# How to change cherrypy request host header so that it will not be returned in the response body

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a cherrypy application that is using the input from the host or x-forwarded-host header in a request and then using it to form a response body that is returned to the client introducing a potential vulnerability. I have tried creating a cherrypy tool that hooks into the on_start_resource point and changes the host and x-forwarded-host headers in the received request to a new value overriding anything that has been sent by the client.

```
        def check_host_header():
            request = cherrypy.request
            cherrypy.request.headers['HOST'] = 'host.blah'
            cherrypy.request.headers['X-FORWARDED-HOST'] = 'host.blah.x'

    cherrypy.tools.check_host_header = cherrypy.Tool('on_start_resource', check_host_header)
```

the tool is running and changing the headers but the response body still contains the original header that was sent by the client. I realize that the request headers have been processed before the on_start_resource hook but this is the earliest hook there is. Can anyone help me see what I'm missing here please?

Comment: Why do you need to rely on such headers at all if you replace them anyway?

Comment: I'm still not sure what your original intention is, but you might want to be aware of the built-in proxy tool: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20730038

Comment: Thank you for the interest. Turns out the tool is to be much simpler than I originally thought, it only has to check the host header against an allow-list and then redirect if it isn't allowed. So there is no response body manipulation required.

Comment: It would be useful for others googling if you posted your solution as an answer below :) TIA